# How to specify scopes for One Tap Sign-in by google in Android?

Tags: android, gmail-api, google-one-tap

Earlier using google sign-in for android one could have specified scopes to read mails of a user, but using Google Identity Services I am not able to find any option to provides scope, one work-around I found was using OAuth2.0 but its non-seamless. Wanted to know if there is any seamless way to specify scopes using One Tap Sign-in